# How to handle uploaded excel file in Django

Tags: python, django

I try to display some data in console during the file upload. I have tested that I can convert uploaded excle files thrue a PANDAS script that way but error occureed.

I used:
in settings.py:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
```

]

view:

```
def excle_upload(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    form = ExcleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        filehandle = request.FILES['file']
        path = filehandle.temporary_file_path
        df = pd.read_excel(path)
        print(df.head())
        form.save()
        return redirect('excle_list')
else:
    form = ExcleForm()

return render(request, 'odo_correction/excle_upload.html', {'form':form})
```

Error:
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'method'>